# XSD choice equivalent in OpenAPI 3

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I am building an API in OpenAPI and want to build something that is equivalent to this XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="InputData"> 
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="input1" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="input2" type="double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> 
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="input3A" type="my:dataType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="input3B" type="my:dataType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

the closest I can come is this:

```
components:
  schemas:
    MyDataType:
      type: object
      properties:
        val1:
          type: string
        val2:
          type: number
          

    InputData:
      type: object
      properties:
        input1:
          type: string
        input2:
          type: string
        input3:
          oneOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyDataType'
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyDataType'
```

But, it doesn't allow the names `input3A` or `input3B` to specify which input I'm providing.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is equivalent to your XSD:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    MyDataType:
      type: object
      properties:
        val1:
          type: string
        val2:
          type: number
          

    InputData:
      allOf:
      - type: object
        properties:
          input1:
            type: string
          input2:
            type: string
        required: [input1, input2]
      - type: object
        oneOf:
          - properties:
              input3A:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyDataType'
            required: [input3A]
          - properties:
              input3B:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyDataType'
            required: [input3B]
```